# Upload a file using Java Swing coupled with php in the server side

Tags: java, php, upload

I have a Java Swing application that needs to upload a file to the server. My server is a an Apache. I know that I can do this with a Servlet but I don't want to install/maintain a Tomcat server. So I'am wondering is it possible to do it with a PHP script in the server side ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do that using jakarta HttpClient library

["Upload file HttpClient"](http://www.einfobuzz.com/2011/09/upload-file-using-java-swing-and-php.html)

The article has both server side (php) and client side (java) code

you need to specify the folder on the PHP code, it is already doing through the method

```
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['userfile'] ['tmp_name'], $_FILES['userfile'] ['name']);
```

This function checks to ensure that the file designated by $_FILES['userfile'] ['tmp_name'] is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by $_FILES['userfile'] ['name'].

Comment: Thanks, but how you set the destination folder ?